# How can I put the regions of my donut chart together?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm creating a donut chart and I would like to join the regions, to avoid these blank spaces.

[image]

how can I do it? thank you very much.

```
  var chart = c3.generate({
      data: {
          columns: [
              ['data1', 30],
              ['data2', 120],
          ],
          type : 'donut',
          onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
          onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
          onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); },
          label:true,
      },
      donut: {
          title: "Iris Petal Width",
           label: {
           /*format: function(value, ratio, id)
           {
             return d3.format('')(value)
           },*/
           show: false
          }
      }
  });
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JD52FXdZxEIcgP865w4h?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add the following CSS rule:

```
.c3-chart-arc path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8VaYAOG1kefAv0xJRtW?p=preview).